# I tried everything but I can't get android studio to work

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm very new to android studio. I want to make a simple android app but I can't add any functionality to my design. When I try to drag a text box into my design view it won't allow me to.

At first, I was getting a lot of rendering errors. I downloaded different versions of SDK, installed all the SDK views and changed the theme. Eventually, those errors stopped showing up. But I still can't add any elements to the design. I'm not sure what is going on.

[image: Here's what it looks like right now]

Comment: How does it fail? Does the "drop" just do nothing after "dragging?"
Or are there any errors? 
I'm relatively new to Studio (used Eclipse before) but it worked "out of the box" for me. On Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: theres a circle with a cross through it

Comment: Personally, I would recommend edit the layout.xml directly instead of using the UI. That will gives you better control and more maintainable code in the future.

Comment: I agree and I use mostly Text. But it doesn't answer the question.
If you edit the Text does it get rendered when you switch to Design?

Answer (score 1):

Layout designer in Android studio or Eclipse sucks.

So if you are learning or even you are pro you should directly use layout.xml file to add and edit the button in that way you will be able to control the layout much better.